# I keep getting the same error for my Add User function

Tags: python, class

i am working on creating a network with classes. However, I keep getting this error for the addUser function:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'getUserName'
```

Here is the code, it would be nice if someone could help me.

```
def addUser(self, users):
    """ Adds a user to be included in the users list by the append method """
    for username in users:  # Compares the new user with the values in the users list to determine the user name was not taken
        if username == users.getUserName():
            print("Sorry, that name is taken. Try again.")
            return
    # If username was not taken, add user to the network
    user_id = len(self.users)
    self.users.append(User(user_id))  # Keeps and tracks down the user ID related to the length of the users list
```

Comment: Simple explanation: you are passing in a string as the `users` argument. Try printing it to see what's happening.

Comment: Could you show me an example, please? I don't really get it

Comment: At the start of your function just add `print(type(users), users)` to see the type of the value and its content. It looks like your code is expecting some class that supports iteration and has a `getUserName` method but the error message implies you're passing it a string instead.